# How come the Tesseract was with Von Strucker?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

If the Tesseract was in Asgard after the Avengers (Thor took it along with Loki) how come Von Strucker had it at the end of *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*? Even more at the end of *Thor: The Dark World* they said that they took the Aether to the Collector since they already had the Tesseract in Asgard. And didn’t want to Infinity Stones be together.

Answer (score 2):

Von Strucker is not in possession of the Tesseract. He is performing experiments using Loki's scepter, which contains a different Infinity Stone. You can see the scene [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32Qh2zXbROA).

Comment: The Tesseract contained the Space Stone. Loki's scepter contained the Mind Stone.